# Use Join in linq Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Class `Image`:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Product`:

```
public partial class Products
{
     public Products()
     {
         Image = new HashSet<Image>();
     }

     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Image> Image { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is :

```
 var product = _context.Products.Find(id);
 var image = product.Image.Where(a => a.ImageCover == true && a.IsDelete == false).SingleOrDefault();
 var imageName = image == null ? "no_image.jpg" : image.ImageName;
```

`var image` is always returning null, I don't know why

Comment: Check the Products table data in the database, whether it contains the related records (ImageCover is true and IsDelete is false)? Perhaps the issue is related that the table doesn't contains the related items. Besides, try to use FirstOrDefault method, instead of the SingleOrDefault method.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no image in the `HashSet` for the specified product, matching the following condition:

```
a.ImageCover == true && a.IsDelete == false
```

`SingleOrDefault` returns `null` for reference types like image is, when there are no results in the `IEnumerable`

For a more specific answer, we'd need the data structure/ source and more implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

EF core does not lazy load children by default. You need to enable it by adding the UseLazyLoadingProxies in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and define the navigation property as virtual to enable the lazy loading. Alternatively, you can explicitly load the children with Load() on the product Image. See https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-loading-eager-lazy for more details on eager/lazy loading options.